# kubernetes graph component in kube ui

Tags: graph, kubernetes

I am able to run the `kube-ui` but I am not able to add the graph component successfully as described in the `README.md`:

https://github.com/kubernetes-ui/graph

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hzU2IV2Dwfc

Has anyone be able to get the graph component to show up in the `kube-ui`?  I cloned the graph component into the `/kube-ui/master/components/` next to the dashboard component that runs.  Is there a manifest.json or something else i need to change in kube-ui?

Note: I am able to get the cluster-insight pod working.  Just the ui javascript part in the `kube-ui` that i can't get working.

Comment: same here. Any progress?

Comment: Do there happen to be updates on things you've learned?

Comment: Still nothing? I was wondering if someone succeed to use this..